# Naming of a class (perhaps a proxy) that allows sorting and removing items without modifying the underlying container

Tags: c++, class, view, proxy, naming

I wonder about what would the appropriate [naming](/questions/tagged/naming) of a [class](/questions/tagged/class) I have developed in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) that stores indices to a container. The basic functionality is the same as a [view](/questions/tagged/view). Items can be modified in the underlying container if it is non-const. However, as the class stores indices to the underlying container it can be made to produce a a view independent of the underlying container i.e. without modifying it. This is done either by sorting the indices or removing them. Is the class then a proxy or what is the appropriate name of such a class? It is relevant to adhere to the prevailing [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) vocabulary.

Comment: Your class is actually a range. Anyway your question is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Is there a better place to ask the question?

Comment: a "view" usually does not allow to modify the actual container

Comment: Your class seems to have similitude with [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).

Comment: I guess that depends on the context. Model/view support modification of the model.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes that is true.

Comment: in mvc yes, but a view of a container is different context ;). Btw I would rather care that you and the users of the class know what the name means. If you think "view" correctly describes it, then probably "view" is a good name

Answer (score 0):

Sorting and removing items without modifying the underlying container sounds like a **filter** or **search**.

Filter tags are normally used for variable names. For example the vector, map or something else that holds indexes or pointers to the items.

Search tags are mostly used for functions and classes. Probably because a search algorithm can easily become complex.